# Multiple AJAX Requests Freezing Browser

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cors

On page load, I'm making two AJAX requests: one to pull the newest video from a Youtube channel, and one to pull the newest post from a blog. Both scripts work correctly.

For whatever reason, I haven't been able to test it in any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera). Is the request too big? I've been running into issues with CORS support (at least that's what I think is going on) while using Chrome, so the blog request isn't working there and completely offsets the video request (it doesn't work).

Here's the error I get in the Javascript Dev Console in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://devingraham.blogspot.com/rss.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If I change...

```
var tmp = $(this).find("content:first").text();
```

...to just find the "title:first" instead, it renders fine in Safari without freezing. If I keep it at content and load the page, I can see the post loads in just fine, but the page freezes and won't load the video. So perhaps it's just too much? I know for a fact that the post I'm pulling is quite long, but it seems silly that it would cause any issues. So do you have any ideas?

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/devinsupertramp/uploads?orderby=updated&alt=rss&client=ytapi-youtube-rss-redirect&v=2",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseVideo
          });
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://devingraham.blogspot.com/rss.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseBlog
          });
    });

    function parseVideo(xml) {
        $(xml).find("item:first").each(
            function() {
                var tmp = $(this).find("link:first").text();
                tmp = tmp.replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "");
                tmp = tmp.replace("&feature=youtube_gdata", "");
                tmp2 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + tmp + "?autoplay=1&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1";
                var iframe = $("#ytplayer");
                $(iframe).attr('src', tmp2);
            }
        );
    }

    function parseBlog(xml) {
        $(xml).find("entry:first").each(
            function() {
                var tmp = $(this).find("content:first").text();
                var post = $("#blog");
                post.append(tmp);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Open Firebug, open the NET tab and take a look at the request/response sequence. This may give you a clue.

Comment: All I can see is that Origin is null. But I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Are you aware of the same origin policy regarding AJAX requests? http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: I have read a little bit about it, but I don't know what it means in regards to my requests or how I can fix it (I'm very new to AJAX/jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you cannot make cross-domain AJAX requests because of the Same Origin Policy.

You can get around this, but it requires the [cooperation of the site on the other domain](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) to explicitly allow this type of request.

See: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: I'll look into these. I guess I didn't realize how convoluted it was regarding request origins.